# HTML 5 Drag and Drop API in React JS

Tags: react-hooks

I have used the HTML5 API of drag and drop in HTML5. Eveything works fine to me but after few days when records are increasing in that case vertical scroll is not working.

e.g. In Left container I have 10 groups and in right container 100 records. From right container I am dragging the content and drop it into groups. But, when I am end of the page in that case I cannot able to drop becasue scroll is not working.

I have tried many script but not working.

Comment: https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/about